# Get <td> inside <tbody> of a <table> using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have table with class tablesorter. In that table is tbody that contains many of tr. In tr is td class=status that showing "UP" text. I need to get in every tr and check if the td class=status is UP. If is not UP then I need to hide that tr. HTML is on the picture.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: [You should not use an image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4370109) but place the code itself in the question with the [edit] button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the list of `tr`s from the table and convert to an array:

```
[...document.querySelector('table').querySelectorAll('tr')]
  // then forEach over the array to conditionally hide the row
  .forEach(tr => {
    // select the element with class 'status' check if txt is not UP
    const el = tr.querySelector('.status');
    if (!el || el.textContent.trim() !== 'UP') {
      tr.style.display = 'none'; // hide tr
    }
  });
```